# Running Mercurial server on Google AppEngine

Tags: google-app-engine, mercurial

I mean something like "hg serve", with HTTP push support.

This is probably not supported out of the box due GAE's read-only file system. If you know of any attempts to do it or analysis of what it would take, please share.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the sake of closure. Yes, someone did this.

[Mercurial on App Engine](http://hg-repos.appspot.com/static/faq.html)