# SourceForge like application (with version control) for GAE?

Tags: google-app-engine

Recently kenai.com was announced to be closed soon so I need to migrate my project to some other hosting. I have started wondering, if there are blog apps you can install and run on GAE, maybe there is some way to setup SVN on GAE? Maybe there is Kenai/SourceForge type app I can put on GAE? Is it possible to setup my own project hosting on GAE?

Comment: I don't know of any VCS that can natively live on the datastore. That seems to be the main issue to me.

Comment: GitFarm is running on App Engine.  I don't believe they've opensourced their code, but it's certainly possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[It's possible to run Mercurial on appengine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/340102/running-mercurial-server-on-google-appengine). Of course, there are plenty SCM hosting solutions now (like [github](http://www.github.com) (git), and [Bitbucket](http://www.bitbucket.org) (mercurial))... which may beat rolling your own

Comment: Yeah, but I was thinking about something free, without licenses limitation, and without requirement for project to be open source.